# Order by slug in get_terms with multiple taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I am builing a search engine where I need to search in 2 different taxonomies and sort them by slug. I got this code to do so.

```
$search = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'search' ] );
$content = '';
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => array('apartments','houses'),
    'search' => $search,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => true
));
```

Right now the result is:

- Apartment A
- Apartment B
- House A
- House B

and i would like it to be like that:

- Apartment A
- House A
- Apartment B
- House B

Any idea as I run out of at the moment ;)
I would like to avoid JS at that moment.

Comment: I'm unsure what kind of order that is, is it reverse order aka `A esuoH`? This ordering doesn't make sense, are the terms grouped together in some other way that isn't being shared?

Comment: I don't think there's an orderby parameter that would order the results as you've described. But you could use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to implement custom order after the terms have been retrieved

Comment: @admcfajn That was a great idea.

This helped do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working @Mastafu

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array_column($terms, 'slug');
array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $terms);
```

That did the trick and let me sort terms in that muli array.